# how to create local dynamic variables

Tags: python, dynamic, python-3.x, eval

this is my code, I want to use `eval()` to get the rule status but `eval()` needs local variables, there is many classes that inherits the base class, so I need to rewrite `get_stat()` in every class.

I want to avoid this, an idea is to create dynamic variables in `get_stat()`,eg. class b dynamically creates variables a and b in func `get_stat()`

How should I create dynamic varables in function? or any other way to avoid this stupid idea. I use python 3.2.3, `locals()` does not work

```
class base(object):
    def check(self):
        stat = get_stat()
    def get_stat(self):
        pass

class b(base):
    rule = 'a > 5 and b < 3'
    a = 0
    b = 0

    def update_data(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def get_stat(self):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        return eval(rule)

class b(base):
    rule = 'd > 5 and e < 3'
    d = 0
    e = 0

    def update_data(self, d, e):
        self.d = d
        self.e = e

    def get_stat(self):
        d = self.d
        e = self.e
        return eval(rule)
```

Comment: i don't see what's dynamic here! You're still re-writing `rule` for every class, you might as well just re-write the function

Comment: @vikki: I suppose it's dynamic in the sense that the `rule` attribute of each subclass can be changed on-the-fly and `get_stat()` will return results based on it's current value. You're right about the fact that `rule` could just as well be made a method, although the syntax needed to change it might not be as convenient or clean looking as would be this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary to the `eval()` function containing the variables to evaluate the expression against:

```
>>> eval("a + b", {"a": 2, "b": 3})
5
```

Pass `self.__dict__` to give access to an object's attributes:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.a = 2
...             self.b = 3
... 
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.__dict__
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
>>> eval("a + b", obj.__dict__)
5
```

Links:

- [eval](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)
- [`__dict__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

Comment: I think to be crystal clear you should state that they could use `return eval(rule, self.__dict__)` or `return eval(rule, vars(self))`.